# How can I grep a text piece from a 1 line text file with delimiters

Tags: command-line, grep, text-processing

I want to `grep` 
`STX= .......` until its first delimiter `'`
and 
`IRF= .....` until its first delimiter `'`.

Like:

```
:STX=ANAA:1+asdf+5060128703127:P'
IRF=16165193117+160624+160624 '
```

Comment: Is this the strings exact output?

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to @terdon and @jhilmer for making the quoting decidedly less tricky

If you want the `'`

```
$ grep -oE "(STX|IRF).*'" file 
STX=ANAA:1+asdf+5060128703127:P'
IRF=16165193117+160624+160624 '
```

If you don't want the `'`

```
$ grep -oE "(STX|IRF)[^']*"
STX=ANAA:1+asdf+5060128703127:P
IRF=16165193117+160624+160624
```

#### Explanation

- `-o` just show the matched part
- `-E` use ERE so we can use `|` to search for multiple patterns
- `"` start quoting/stop quoting
- `(THIS|THAT)` match `THIS` or `THAT`
- `.*` match any number of any characters
- `\'` literal `'`
- `[^']*` any number of any characters except `'`

Comment: `grep -oE "(STX|IRF)[^']*" file`

Comment: You can also double quote your first approach so you don't need to escape the single one: `grep -oE "(STX|IRF).*'" file `